# Migrate a Traversable that uses a visitor to an Iterable in Scala 2.13

Tags: scala, migration, iterable, visitor-pattern, scala-2.13

The [migration guide to Scala 2.13](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/collections-migration-213.html) explains that `Traversable` has been removed and that `Iterable` should be used instead. This change is particularly annoying for one project, which is using a visitor to implement the `foreach` method in the `Node` class of a tree:

```scala
case class Node(val subnodes: Seq[Node]) extends Traversable[Node] {
  override def foreach[A](f: Node => A) = Visitor.visit(this, f)
}

object Visitor {
  def visit[A](n: Node, f: Node => A): Unit = {
    f(n)
    for (sub <- n.subnodes) {
      visit(sub, f)
    }
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  val a = Node(Seq())
  val b = Node(Seq())
  val c = Node(Seq(a, b))
  for (Node(subnodes) <- c) {
    Console.println("Visiting a node with " + subnodes.length + " subnodes")
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Visiting a node with 2 subnodes
Visiting a node with 0 subnodes
Visiting a node with 0 subnodes
```

An easy fix to migrate to Scala 2.13 is to first store the visited elements in a `remaining` buffer, which is then used to return an iterator:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

case class Node(val subnodes: Seq[Node]) extends Iterable[Node] {
  override def iterator: Iterator[Node] = {
    val remaining = mutable.Queue.empty[Node]
    Visitor.visit(this, item => iterator.remaining.enqueue(item))
    remaining.iterator
  }
}

// Same Visitor object
// Same Main object
```

This solution has the disadvantages that it introduces new allocations that put pressure on the GC, because the number of visited elements is usually quite large.

Do you have suggestions on how to migrate from `Traversable` into `Iterable`, using the existing visitor but without introducing new allocations?

Comment: Since when `new Foo {}` uses reflection? Anyways, take a look to the `unfold` method on **Iterator**.

Comment: Good point, I misinterpreted an error message.

Comment: Is your visitor exactly like in the code? Because this could be implemented with `LazyList`,`.flatMap` and recursion.

Comment: @mateusz-kubuszok The original visitor is very similar (see [here](https://github.com/viperproject/silver/blob/318a553d67be538ff0b7c526d9f805edb6256c4f/src/main/scala/viper/silver/ast/utility/Visitor.scala#L14-L21)). Since it's called in a lot of places I was looking for a solution that doesn't modify it. I still don't see how a `LazyList` would prevent the allocations. Do you mean that an iterator over a `LazyList` never allocates the full list?

Comment: Yes, LazyList performs side effect (allocation of space for new values, computation of new values that were passed as a recipies for values and not already computed valued) on access and then remembers what it already computed - but if you create an Iterator from LazyList it will let the `LazyList` "forget" everything that is not needed to compute further values and reclaim the memory by GC.

Comment: As a matter of the fact Iterator just as Traversable are just interfaces which doesn't rely on knowing all values ahead. When you do `Iterator.from(0).drop(1000000).take(4).toList` you don't allocate 1000000 values upfront. You only do allocate each value when it is needed.

Comment: One more solution that we are considering is to declare our own `Traversable` trait. The advantage is that there is no need to reimplement the visitor's logic.

Comment: @TomerShetah I ended up adding my own definition of a minimal `Traversable` trait to solve the issue. This way the visitor doesn't need to be refactored and no other overhead is introduced.

Answer (score 3):

As you noticed, you need to extend `Iterable` instead of `Traversable`. You can do it like this:

```
case class Node(name: String, subnodes: Seq[Node]) extends Iterable[Node] {
  override def iterator: Iterator[Node] = Iterator(this) ++ subnodes.flatMap(_.iterator)
}

val a = Node("a", Seq())
val b = Node("b", Seq())
val c = Node("c", Seq(a, b))
val d = Node("d", Seq(c))

for (node@Node(name, _) <- d) {
  Console.println("Visiting node " + name + " with " + node.subnodes.length + " subnodes")
}
```

outputs:

```
Visiting node d with 1 subnodes
Visiting node c with 2 subnodes
Visiting node a with 0 subnodes
Visiting node b with 0 subnodes
```

Then you can do more operations such as:

```
d.count(_.subnodes.length > 1)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/qUR9I1HwQQaXRuqj2YSAcg/1).

Comment: That's actually a nice solution for the minimal example that I posted. However, the original project also calls `withFilter` and other methods on `Node`.

Comment: @Federico, Seems like currently you can't do filter as well: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/qUR9I1HwQQaXRuqj2YSAcg

Comment: You are right, calling `filter` in the example leads to a stack overflow. I might have removed too much from the original project. However, this works and gives a compilation error if you remove the `extends`: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6CFD3kHnTo2oVgFXnQG4xQ

Comment: Like the `LazyList` this solution requires to reimplement the visitor's logic, but effectively I don't see a way to avoid it. Am I right in evaluating that the inner `_.iterator`s are all executed together? This would mean that a sequence of iterators might be allocated for each level of the tree.

Comment: @Federico basically how I see it, you can drop the `Visitor`. My code reaches all nodes without it. Please note that in your example the `iterator` is just the initiator, and `visitor` makes all nodes reachable. But yes, all nodes in the same level are going to be in the iterator. BUT! the fact that from scratch `subnodes` is declared as `Seq` means this is already being done. Maybe you should consider holding `subnodes` as `iterator` instead of `Seq`

Answer (score 2):

This is an example that your code can be implemented with `LazyList` and that visitor is not needed:

```
case class Node(val subnodes: Seq[Node]) {
  
  def recursiveMap[A](f: Node => A): LazyList[A] = {
    def expand(node: Node): LazyList[Node] = node #:: LazyList.from(node.subnodes).flatMap(expand)
    expand(this).map(f)
  }
}

val a = Node(Seq())
val b = Node(Seq())
val c = Node(Seq(a, b))

val lazyList = c.recursiveMap { node =>
  println("computing value")
  "Visiting a node with " + node.subnodes.length + " subnodes"
}

println("started computing values")

lazyList.iterator.foreach(println)
```

output

```
started computing values
computing value
Visiting a node with 2 subnodes
computing value
Visiting a node with 0 subnodes
computing value
Visiting a node with 0 subnodes
```

If you won't store `lazyList` reference yourself and only iterator, then JVM would be able to GC values as you go.

Answer (score 2):

We ended up writing a minimal `Traversable` trait, implementing just the methods that are used in our codebase. This way there is no additional overhead and the visitor's logic doesn't need to be changed.

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable

/** A trait for traversable collections. */
trait Traversable[+A] {
  self =>

  /** Applies a function to all element of the collection. */
  def foreach[B](f: A => B): Unit

  /** Creates a filter of this traversable collection. */
  def withFilter(p: A => Boolean): Traversable[A] = new WithFilter(p)

  class WithFilter(p: A => Boolean) extends Traversable[A] {
    /** Applies a function to all filtered elements of the outer collection. */
    def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit = {
      for (x <- self) {
        if (p(x)) f(x)
      }
    }

    /** Further refines the filter of this collection. */
    override def withFilter(q: A => Boolean): WithFilter = {
      new WithFilter(x => p(x) && q(x))
    }
  }

  /** Finds the first element of this collection for which the given partial
    * function is defined, and applies the partial function to it.
    */
  def collectFirst[B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): Option[B] = {
    for (x <- self) {
      if (pf.isDefinedAt(x)) {
        return Some(pf(x))
      }
    }
    None
  }

  /** Builds a new collection by applying a partial function to all elements
    * of this collection on which the function is defined.
    */
  def collect[B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): Iterable[B] = {
    val elements = mutable.Queue.empty[B]
    for (x <- self) {
      if (pf.isDefinedAt(x)) {
        elements.append(pf(x))
      }
    }
    elements
  }
}
```